# Playlists getting duplicated

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, ipad, playlist

When I sync my iPad to my MacBook, a lot of my playlists are getting duplicated over and over again. Here is an example:

[image]

It happens to regular and smart-playlists.

I am on iTunes 12.4.1.6.

How do I stop this mass duplication?

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the duplicated playlists from my computer and then delete the same playlists on my iPhone in order to get rid of the duplicates. Still, I have duplicates on my Macbook